# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined (React & Firestore)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having issues sending some data through to state using Firestore. I am trying to get the autogenerated ID that the store creates when a new question is added to my course.

Here's my some chunks of my code:

**Editquestions.js**

```
state = {
      question: '',
      questions: [],
      courseUrl: '',
      questionIds: [],
}
  
getData =() => {
      let db = firebase.firestore()
      let courseID = this.props.match.params.course;

       db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).collection('questions').get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            const questionIds = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                const id = doc.id
                questionIds.push(id)
                console.log(questionIds)
            })
            this.setState({questionIds})
            console.log(this.state.questionIds)
        }).catch(error => {console.error(error)})
    }
```

The error I am recieving is

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined`

Currently, I know the Ids are being picked up since the console.log:

```
console.log(questionIds)
```

Works correctly, I am just unable to push this data to state.

Comment: Is the code you've posted wrapped in a component? can you post the full code?

Comment: This could will "work" in a Component  not in a function since it has no "this"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function syntax to arrow syntax to get implicit reference of `this` for component:

```
db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).collection('questions').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            const questionIds = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                const id = doc.id
                questionIds.push(id)
                console.log(questionIds)
            })
            this.setState({questionIds})
            console.log(this.state.questionIds)
        }).catch(error => {console.error(error)})
```

Answer (score 0):

You then function does not have `this` of your component. Bind `this` to your function inside `then` or use arrow function.

```
getData =() => {
      let db = firebase.firestore()
      let courseID = this.props.match.params.course;

       db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).collection('questions').get().then(function(querySnapshot){
            const questionIds = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                const id = doc.id
                questionIds.push(id)
                console.log(questionIds)
            })
            this.setState({questionIds})
            console.log(this.state.questionIds)
        }.bind(this)).catch(error => {console.error(error)})
    }
```

or

```
getData =() => {
      let db = firebase.firestore()
      let courseID = this.props.match.params.course;

       db.collection('courses').doc(courseID).collection('questions').get().then((querySnapshot) => {
            const questionIds = []
            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
                const id = doc.id
                questionIds.push(id)
                console.log(questionIds)
            })
            this.setState({questionIds})
            console.log(this.state.questionIds)
        }).catch(error => {console.error(error)})
    }
```